# How to disable stdout or stderr by vscode executing from msys2 bash

Tags: visual-studio-code, msys2

I usually use VSCode from msys2 bash.
I got some standard output or standard error on msys2 terminal.
Following shows an example.

```
$ vscode . &
[main 2021-01-06T13:52:08.063Z] update#setState idle
[main 2021-01-06T13:52:38.071Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2021-01-06T13:52:38.274Z] update#setState idle
```

Those logs do not appear when VSCode was executed from PowerShell.

```
PS > .\Code.exe
PS >
```

How can I disable those stdout or stderr by VSCode executing from msys2 bash?
I could not find any solution because there are so many information about
integrating msys2 bash on VSCode.

Comment: I get that output in powershell v5.x.  Also looking to turn it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71289#issuecomment-477481163), try running `code.cmd` in `~/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin`, not Code.exe in the parent folder.